# Empty Patch created on Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I've been reading various tutorials on how to use Mercurial, and have been trying to create a patch containing my changes using hg qnew (e.g. hg qnew Enumpatch.patch). However it just keeps coming up with an empty patch. I've tried reading around and googling and am none the wiser. I think it's probably something really obvious. Can anyone help me?

When I do hg status I get:

```
$ hg status
M series
A Enum
```

so it can't see the changes I have done previously.   Is there a way of rectifying this?

I'm doing the following steps on Mercurial:

```
$ echo >FormAssistPopup.java 
$ hg add FormAssistPopup.java 
FormAssistPopup.java already tracked!
$ hg commit -m "Enum patch."
abort: cannot commit over an applied mq patch
$ hg qnew Enum.patch
Enum.patch already tracked!
```

It won't let me commit over an applied patch, but when I try and create a new patch it says 'patch already tracked', despite the fact it has been removed from the patches folder and from the series file.  Is there any way round this?

Comment: Does your change consist of anything other than modified existing files? For instance, you still have to `hg add` new files before *either* `hg qnew` or `hg commit`.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to commit the files I had modified previously to a patch so someone can give me feedback on my patch.

Comment: How did you determine that the patch is empty? Does the patch show as a revision in `hg log`? If it does, what happens if you try `hg log -v -r [patch revision]`?

Comment: I opened the patch in a text editor and could see that it was empty.  When I do hg status I can see that my patch has been added, but it's blank.  Is there a way of rectifying that?

Comment: @MichaelNares how are you creating the patch? Can you post the steps you're using?

Comment: The ones here:  http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqTutorial.

Comment: hq init --mq > hg qnew Enum.patch > hg qrefresh > hg qfinish Enum.patch.  I now get cannot delete revision 143047 above applied patches.  I'm rather baffled as to why this won't work.

Comment: Does anyone know what this error message means?  I've tried googling it.  It may well be it's something really obvious.

Comment: Why do you use hg init --mq? First learn how to use MQs properly. Later, you can use advanced stuff such as --mq.

Comment: What version of Mercurial and does your patch contain only binary files?  Older versions didn't automatically use the extended diff `--git` format so binary files weren't added to patches unless the switch was specified.

Comment: I'm using Mercurial 2.6.2 and no I'm not only using binary files.

Comment: @Ringding: `hg init --mq` is the way you initialise MQ for a repository... without that, how can you learn about MQ?

Comment: No, --mq creates/operates on a repository for your MQ patches, which is completely unnecessary when starting with MQ. The MQ patches themselves are just a series of files and don't need a repository.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to really know what you are doing wrong, but here's the basic sequence to create a patch.  Perhaps that will help:

Make a repository:

```
hg init example
cd example
```

Commit a file to it:

```
echo >file1
hg add file1
hg commit -m "First file."
```

Make some changes:

```
echo >>file1
echo >file2
hg add file2
```

Create the patch:

```
hg qnew mypatch
```

Make another change:

```
echo >>file2
```

Update the current patch:

```
hg qrefresh
```

Make another change:

```
echo >>file1
echo >>file2
```

Start a new patch:

```
hg qnew Patch2
```

Remove the most recent patch:

```
hg qpop
```

Comment: Michaels-MacBook-Air:src michael$ hg qnew Enum2.patch
repository tip rolled back to revision 143048 (undo commit)
working directory now based on revision 143048
abort: Enum2.patch appears more than once in /Users/michael/src/.hg/patches/series

Comment: I'm getting this now, is there any way round this, would I just go into the series file and delete it?

Comment: *shrug*, I don't know how you got in that state to begin with, but deleting entries in the series file won't lose you any work, so it is worth a try.  If you could update your question with reproducible steps to get that error it would be helpful.

Comment: Changing your question to another question doesn't help.  Now none of the comments make sense since they are about the last question.  There is still missing information about how you got into this state. We could continue this in chat.

Comment: Ideally, restore your original question, but add new information to completely reproduce the steps from a new database that cause the error message to appear.

Comment: OK done,  as I seem to be struggling to get an answer on this issue I will try either e-mailing Mercurial or seeing if they have an IRC group, whilst keeping this open.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37828/discussion-between-mark-tolonen-and-michael-nares)